# Removing a package from External libraries in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to remove the `/usr/bin/python2.7/dist-packages/gi package` from `External Libraries` list in my PyCharm project because I don't want PyCharm to pick up code completion cues from this package. Why I want to do it? Because I'm overriding it with another `gi` package in some other directory, and both of them being there causes code completion issues.

Yes I'm aware my PyGI code won't run without the actual `gi` package, I'm just doing this for ease of editing.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to uninstall the `gi` package in your Python's environment. Simply run `pip uninstal gi`. You can install it back later when you want.

Or, you could create a [`virtualenv`](http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-power-tools-virtualenv--net-31560), and just use the packages that you want to be made available to you.